# How to randomly select numbers within an arbitrary range and add together using JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I am trying to write some JavaScript that will select some random numbers from an array and then add those selected numbers to make a single total value.

For example if i had `var array = [1, 22, 5, 88, 3, 105, 7, 88, 987]` i would then like the code to select however many numbers it wants at random(amount selected changes every time it runs) and then add them together but i am not sure if this is even possible.

I am new to JavaScript so i have only managed to write code that adds all the array elements together instead of selecting at random.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var total=0;
    for(var i in arr) { total += arr[i]; }
```

My code is very basic so please excuse me for this i'm still learning. Thank You

Comment: Here is how to grab a random one, just need to do it every time you need and add the result each time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Math.rand()` function in order to create a random index. In terms of code:

```
// The array with your elements
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

// An array that will keep track of the elements we have selected.
var selectedIndex = [];

// The sum.
var sum=0;

// times is the number of elements we want to select from arr and sum them.
for(var i=0; i<times; i++)
{
    // Get a random integer number in the range [0, arr.length]
    var index = Math.floor(Math.rand()*arr.length);

    // check if the index we created has been selected again.
    if(selectedIndex.indexOf(index)>-1)
    {
        // The created index has been selected again. So we must select another one,
        // in order we get an item from the array only once.        
        while(selectedIndex.indexOf(index)>-1)
            index = Math.floor(Math.rand()*arr.length);    
    }

    // We push the created index in the selected index array.
    selectedIndex.push(index);

    // We increase the sum.
    sum+=arr[index];
}
```

**update**

In order the above to be executed the caller should provide a value for the variable called `times`. This value in order to be valid shouldn't exceed the length of the array called `arr`.

Another way more elegant, it would be to follow on this part the solution that [deitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736714/deitch) suggested in his post.

```
var times = Math.floor((Math.random() * arr.length)+1)
```

The above should be placed just before the `for` statement.

Comment: Yeah, I like this one too. As long as you make sure you don't select the same element twice, you are OK. I will upvote this.

Comment: Thank you for this :) when i run the code it keeps telling me that times is not defined any ideas? I am using TextPad(not my choice)

Comment: @user2982634 you welcome dude ! You have to provide a value for the `times` variable.

Comment: oh so i just enter any number instead of the word times?

Comment: @user2982634 yup. Provided that this number is not greater than the length of your array.

Comment: That is brilliant thank you. I haven't managed to get the code to work in TextPad as some methods not supported but hopefully i will shortly

Answer (score 1):

```
I think you are looking something like:

<code>
function randormTotal() {
             var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
             var total=0;
             var noOfData = 3;
             for(var i =0; i<noOfData; i++) { 
               var pos = Math.floor(Math.random()*(arr.length-1)) + 1;             
               total += arr[pos];
             }
             alert(total);
         }
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this method actually modifies the array, so you might want to copy it.

```
// randomly select how many elements you will pick
var i, total = 0, elmsCount = Math.floor((Math.random() * arr.length)+1), current;
// select that many elements
for (i=0; i<elmsCount; i++) {
  current = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length);
  total += arr.splice(current,1)[0];
}
// total is now the sum
```